# Python :- func() got multiple values for keyword?

Tags: python

I've a function:-

```
class CLASS(object):
    def execute(self, a, b, c, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

obj = CLASS()
```

Why does the following code not work?

```
obj.execute(a=a,b=b,c=c, *args, **kwargs)
```

It throws an exception saying `execute got multiple values for a`.

But the below work?

```
obj.execute(a,b,c, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Do you *literally* pass `*args` and `**kwargs`? What are they?

Comment: Guess: `kwargs` includes an `a` key…?

Comment: No, it does not. I've cross-checked it.

Comment: Then please provide a complete sample with which we can reproduce the behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `kwargs` is `{'a': 'foo'}`, then this:

```
obj.execute(a=a, b=b, c=c, *args, **kwargs)
```

is equivalent to this:

```
obj.execute(a=a, b=b, c=c, a='foo')
```

I.e. you're passing `a` twice, once coming from the explicit `a=a` and once from `**kwargs`. However:

```
obj.execute(a, b, c, *args, **kwargs)
```

resolves to

```
obj.execute(a, b, c, a='foo')
```

Here you only explicitly name the parameter `a` with the value `'foo'`, the rest of the parameters are positional and will assign to `b`, `c` and `*args`.

Comment: No, its not the case. `kwargs` does not include `a`. I've cross checked it.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `args` parameter which you're passing in `obj.execute(a=a,b=b,c=c, *args, **kwargs)` is non-empty, which is the equivalent of: `obj.execute(FIRST_VALUE_OF_ARGS, a=a,b=b,c=c, **kwargs)`.

```
>>> class CLASS(object):
        def execute(self, a, b, c, *args, **kwargs):
            print('hi')

>>> obj = CLASS()
>>> obj.execute(a=1,b=2,c=3, *[1], **{})
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-95b963580dd9> in <module>()
----> 1 obj.execute(a=1,b=2,c=3, *[1], **{})

TypeError: execute() got multiple values for argument 'a'
```

The error disappears if the list is empty:

```
>>> obj.execute(a=1,b=2,c=3, *[], **{})
hi
```

Comment: Why does the error goes when `obj.execute(a,b,c, *args, **kwargs)`.

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast because in that case there is no ambiguity, you're explicitly passing the three initial positional arguments, and whatever is in the args is considered "the remaining positional arguments" (which the method is accepting in `*args`). The key thing to realize is that positional arguments are assigned values according to their *position* in the argument sequence. Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

**kwargs creates a dictionary key value pair list.  iterate the items in the dictionary.  Assign constructor variable values using self.

```
class aClass:
    a=""
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a=a
    def print_all(self,**kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            print(self.a+":"+key+":"+value)
      
obj=aClass("Boise")
obj.print_all(name="david nishimoto", occupation="programmer")
```

output:

```
Boise:name:david nishimoto
Boise:occupation:programmer
```